# De Broglie wave speed

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-velocity

I have a very introductory level in quantum mecanics and something remains unclear.

Let $v$ be the speed of a particle (non-relativistic). From De Broglie, we have $p=h/\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength associated to the particle and $p=mv$ is the momentum.

We also have $E=h/T$, where $T$ is the period associated to the particle (seen as a wave).

Thus, $v = \lambda/T = E/p$. Since $E = p^2/2m$, we get $v = p/2m = v/2$.

This looks very contradictory. What is the problem with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between *group velocity* and *phase velocity* of waves?

Answer (score 1):

The two $v$'s on the left- and right-hand-side of your final equation are not actually the same velocity.  There are two velocities associated with waves: the phase velocity and the group velocity.  For light traveling in a [non-dispersive medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation), like a vacuum, the speed of the wave is independent of frequency.  In this case the group and phase velocities are equal.  That is not the case for matter waves.

The [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) of a wave is given by your expression
$$ v_\mathrm{phase} = \frac{\lambda}{T}.$$
This can also be written using different wave variables, that are more commonly used in dispersion relations:
$$ v_\mathrm{phase} = \frac{\omega}{k}, $$
where $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$ is the angular frequency and $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is the wavenumber.

The [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) of the wave is defined:
$$ v_\mathrm{group} = \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial k}.$$
A particle is a wave packet, not a long continuous wave, and the speed of the particle is given by the group velocity of the de Broglie wave.

Using the new variables $\omega$ and $k$ we can rewrite the de Broglie relations and then calculate the group velocity.
$$ E = \hbar \omega \quad\quad p = \hbar k. $$
Because $\hbar$ is a constant, $ \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial k} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial p}$.
The $v$ in the kinetic energy and momentum equations **is** the velocity of the particle:
$$v_\mathrm{group} = \frac{\partial}{\partial p} \left( \frac{p^2}{2m} \right) = \frac{p}{m} = v_\mathrm{particle}. $$

The phase velocity of a matter wave is half of the particle's speed:
$$v_\mathrm{phase} = \frac{E}{p} = \frac{p}{2m} = \frac{v_\mathrm{particle}}{2}. $$